# Is the set of coefficients connected for monic polynomial with roots bounded by some interval?

Tags: general-topology, polynomials, connectedness, path-connected

Suppose we have a monic polynomial with real coefficients
\begin{align*}
p(x) = x^n + \alpha_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \dots + \alpha_1 x + \alpha_0.
\end{align*}
Let $M > 0$ be some fixed real number and let
\begin{align*}
  E = \{ (\alpha_{n-1}, \dots, \alpha_0)^T: \text{modulus of roots of } p(x) \text{ lie in } (-M, M)\}. 
\end{align*}
Is $E$ a connected set considered as a subset of $\mathbb R^n$? Intuitively, it should be so since the roots continuously depend on the coefficients.

Comment: The coefficients of a monic poly can be explicitly written as continuous functions of the roots. Thus $E$ is the continuous image of $(-M,M)^{n}$ (the space of roots), which is connected.

Comment: @DanielLittlewood: Thanks for your comment. Can you provide a proof or a reference for this statement: coefficients are continuous functions of roots? I only know the roots are continuous functions of coefficients.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas

Comment: @DanielLittlewood Actually, there is a subtlety: $E$ is contained in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:** $E$ is connected.

**Proof:**  Let $\Delta$ denote the set $\left\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < M \text{ and } \Im(z) \geq 0 \right\}$ - which is connected.
Now, for $0 \leq k \leq \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$, let $\Gamma_{k}$ denote the image of $\Delta^{k} \times (-M, M)^{n -2 k}$ by the continuous function $f_{k} : \mathbb{C}^{k} \times \mathbb{C}^{n -2 k} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{n}$ defined by $$f_{k}\left(\alpha_{1}, ..., \alpha_{k}, \beta_{1}, ..., \beta_{n -2 k}\right) = \left(\alpha_{1}, \overline{\alpha_{1}}, ..., \alpha_{k}, \overline{\alpha_{k}}, \beta_{1}, ..., \beta_{n -2 k}\right)$$
Then, for every integer $0 \leq k \leq \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$, the set $\Gamma_{k}$ is connected and contains $(-M, M)^{n}$.
It follows that the set $$\Gamma = \bigcup_{k = 0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} \Gamma_{k}$$ is connected.
Thus, the set $$E = \left\{ \left(a_{0}, ..., a_{n -1}\right) \in \mathbb{R}^{n} : \text{ all the roots of } x^{n} +\sum_{k = 0}^{n -1} a_{k} x^{k} \in \mathbb{R}[x] \text{ have modulus } < M \right\}$$ - which is the image of $\Gamma$ by the continuous function $g : \mathbb{C}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{n}$ defined by $$g\left(x_{1}, ..., x_{n}\right) = \left( (-1)^{n -k} \sum_{1 \leq i_{1} < ... < i_{n -k} \leq n} x_{i_{1}} ... x_{i_{n -k}} \right)_{0 \leq k \leq n -1}$$ - is connected.

**P.S:** The image of $\left\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < M\right\}^{n}$ by the function $g$ is the set $$\left\{ \left(a_{0}, ..., a_{n -1}\right) \in \mathbb{C}^{n} : \text{ all the roots of } x^{n} +\sum_{k = 0}^{n -1} a_{k} x^{k} \in \mathbb{C}[x] \text{ have modulus } < M \right\}$$ which is different from $E$.

Comment: One can even replace "connected" by "path-connected" everywhere in my answer to obtain that $E$ is path-connected.

Comment: Am I missing something? Since the coefficients appear in conjugate pairs, then above comments should give the answer by Vieta's formula.

Comment: Actually, the above comments show that the set $E'$ defined in my P.S is connected. But $E = E' \cap \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: I see. Vieta's formula tells us the coefficients are continuous functions of roots but here we want something that are continuous functions on modulus of roots. Is that right?

Comment: No, I don't think so. @DanielLittlewood and I suggest to use the fact that the image of a connected set by a continuous function is connected. However, DanielLittlewood says that - using Vieta's formulas - $E$ is the image of $\left\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < M \right\}^{n}$ - which is not true. Indeed, if you take for example $n = 2$ and $M = 2$, then $(0, -i) = g(0, i) \notin E$. To get the desired result, I say that - using Vieta's formulas - $E$ is the image of the set $\Gamma$ - which is connected - by $g$.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reference for your proof?

Comment: No, sorry. I have made it myself.

Comment: Here is a similar situation so that you understand why the fact that $E'$ is connected does not automatically imply that $E = E' \cap \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is connected. We know that - it is a classic result - the image of $M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ by the exponential map is $GL_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ - which shows that $GL_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ is connected. However, $GL_{n}(\mathbb{R}) = GL_{n}(\mathbb{C}) \cap M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is not connected - its image by the determinant is $\mathbb{R} \backslash \left\{ 0 \right\}$ which is not connected.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks so much.

Comment: I concede, good answer!